# controller problems with angular

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to sign up via Facebook and Twitter with angularFire.
I have 3 href and each should have its template and controller.
However, when I click Sign Up with Twitter, the template calls the twitter controller and the Facebook controller, as supposed to just call the twitter controller. Any idea why this is happening?

**HTML**

```
<div class="il signUpBox" ng-show="showSP">
    <a  href="#createProfileTwitter" role="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="loginTwitter()"> Sign up with Twitter</a></br>
    <a  href="#createProfileFacebok" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loginFacebook()">Sign up with Facebook</a></br>
    <a  href="#createProfile" role="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="CreateYourAccount()"> Create your Account</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){ $routeProvider
.when("/account", {
  templateUrl: "templates/signInView.html"
})
.when("/createProfileTwitter", {
  templateUrl: "templates/createProfileTwitter.html",
  controller: "AccControllerTwitter"
})
.when("/createProfileFacebook", {
  templateUrl: "templates/createProfileFacebook.html",
  controller: "AccControllerFacebook"
})
.otherwise({
  templateUrl: "templates/signInView.html",
}) })
```

Comment: maybe because you have not assigned a controller to /account?

Comment: What do the loginTwitter() and loginFacebook() functions do? Why do you have both an ng-click and an href for the links? Have you noticed that the path in the link is #createProfileFacebok (with a missing o)?